NSF Mathematical Sciences Postdoc fellowship: same institution, different department
For anyone who is familiar with the review process of the NSF Mathematical Sciences Postdoctoral Research Fellowship (MSPRF), I am wondering about the issue with staying at the same institution for the postdoc.
I will earn my PhD from a different department, but the proposal (as currently written) is for hosting in a different department, at the same university. I am wondering how detrimental this is in the review of the application?
One potentially mitigating factor is that my advisor moved to a different university during my PhD, so I actually ended up spending half of my PhD at a different place, even though I am formally earning my degree from the original university (the same one I am applying for the postdoc).
Has anyone here been on a panel to review MSPRF? If so, in your experience is an application of this type dead-on-arrival, or is it still possibly competitive. If the latter, what were the mitigating circumstances?
Update: Here is the relevant portion of the application on research.gov


Why do you think it is detrimental? I can't see any issues?

There is a field in the MSPRF that specifically calls this item out, that was the reason for my interest.

The question presumes a negative impact of the arrangement and then asks us to explain. You're getting ahead of yourself. Write to the relevant NSF program officer, ask how to fill out the form, and then ask for any particular tips in making the application successful.

Your proposal will be evaluated by NSF for the quality of the research you are proposing, your likelihood of succeeding in your plans given your track record and other factors,and the ability of your host institution and department to support you.
No one will care that your postdoc institution is the same as your PhD one, that simply has no bearing on any of the above criteria and is irrelevant information.
Edit: okay, I see based on your update that the NSF actually asks for an explanation for these sorts of circumstances, so here are some thoughts about why they are asking and what you might say. My impression is that the people in charge of the program are assuming that people generally do a postdoc elsewhere than where they got their doctoral degree, and that that's the "correct" thing to do for a successful postdoc, but want to make some allowance for the possibility of some applicants deviating from that standard course and still considering their applications and giving them a chance to prove themselves competitive for the fellowship. The extra justification gives the applicant a place to explain what's going on, since without an explanation, staying in the same place seems like a strange thing to do and potentially indicates a person who finished their PhD but doesn't have a really well thought-out plan to take their research into new and exciting places.
A second thing I'm noticing is the language of the form suggests that the people who wrote it haven't really considered the "same institution, different department" scenario, since the form only refers to "place of performance", leaving some ambiguity about whether that refers to the institution or to the department. Thus, in some sense you could quite reasonably state that the "place of performance" for your postdoc is actually different from where you got your degree.
That doesn't mean I advise picking the first option in the form (the one where you wouldn't need to provide a justification) - that could potentially make you look dishonest or evasive if someone notices you're staying in the same institution. Instead, I think the correct thing to do is to pick the third option, and in the "Justification" text box to enter a straightforward description of the situation. The relevant facts are:

you're staying in the same institution.

you'd be working in a different department.

you'd be working with different people, and in particular your postdoc mentor would be a different person than your PhD advisor. (Assuming that's true; if it's not the case and you are in fact planning to continue working with the same people you were working with during your PhD, then you might look like a less independent and mature researcher than other applicants, which would likely put you at a competitive disadvantage.)

etc - any other information that helps explain why your plan to move to that department is good and would lead to good outcomes for your research.


Bottom line, what I initially said in my original answer still holds. The thing reviewers will care about is that your research plan is good, so that's what you should aim to demonstrate, both in your main proposal and in any supporting texts such as this justification field. It's certainly possible to have a good research plan that involves moving to a different department in the same institution. (It's also possible to have a bad research plan with these parameters, and equally possible to have a bad research plan that involves moving institutions.) So again, I think this is a non-issue and will not hurt your application, provided you give a reasonable explanation of the situation.
Good luck with the application in any case!

Thanks. The genesis of my question was that this question is specifically asked by NSF in the application materials---they ask people who are staying at the same institution to justify why they need to do so.

@DrewBrady - well, justify that. You started already with respect to a different department and not truly being there the whole time. No show what the new department brings you.

Perhaps your situation is other than "you need to do so" and it is just an opportunity.

@DrewBrady okay, that makes a bit more sense. Can you post the exact text of the question you need to answer, or a link? That doesn't really change my opinion that this issue is irrelevant to how competitive your application would be, but it's reasonable to ask what is the best way to address your situation in the context of the explanation you are being asked to provide in the application, so I'll be happy to comment on that.

@DrewBrady can you clarify in your question what language you are citing that mentions this?  I'm looking at the solicitation and see as part of the project description: "a justification of the choice of sponsoring scientist and host institution"--this means you have to justify the choice regardless of who they are and where they are.  The idea here is to ensure that you are choosing the right scientific environment to make you successful.  This is reaffirmed in the "Sponsoring Scientist Statement" document.  Also when you want help on a solicitation, you should always provide the exact link.

@DanRomik I have added a screenshot of the part of the application I am referring to.

@DrewBrady, speaking as a research administrator, I would guide you to continue with your plan if you think it is a good one.  You need to have a real explanation for why you chose this path.  In the case of sponsored research, sponsors do allow exceptional things all the time -- it's all about the justification.  Many people do not spend the time to do these sections, and they are eliminated quickly for a lack of a cohesive plan.  If you take it seriously and have an actual reason for your choice, you should explain and be fine.  If you can have a PI review it, that would be best.

Thanks a lot. I also sent an inquiry to one of the program admins to see what they say. However, if I don't get an answer, then (3) is the best option -- "honesty is the best policy."
I think I can easily justify that (a) it is a move to a new department; (b) my sponsoring scientist will be able to help with tracking references, explaining etc. the new tools I plan to use in my research; (c) my sponsor is NOT my thesis advisor (nor is he on my committee, in fact was hired in my penultimate year of PhD). Hopefully this ensures the only thing that matters is the quality of the proposal!
